# Advance a file object more than one line as a way of skipping blank lines and lines containing strings

Tags: python, file, iterator, iteration

`next()` iterates to the next line in a file, but what if you want to iterate by 2 or 3 lines and then read that file.  Example: say you want to add a number to an amount from a file. But in order to get to that number you must skip a file that contains 2 lines that are just letters.

I've tried something like `amount = next(); next()` and that did not work, or I am using it incorrectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters nope, your wrong. You need to unmark as duplicate because their method and my method and purpose are very different.

Comment: The alternative was to close your post as unclear; what you are doing is not clear to me at all and I took one possible interpretation. Giving you a duplicate is better in such cases as a partial answer is better than nothing at all. Note that it is the *answers* on a dupe that count here. If you still disagree, see ["This question may already have an answer here" - but it does not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252) for your options here.

Comment: @Matijn Pieters I'd like to live in a world where I post a meaningful question that is direct and to the point. That has been removed of all fluff. and that is in the context specific to the question. I.e. I didn't post any code of mine unrelated to this specific question. I want to live in that world and so I posted this question keeping that world in mind. Everything was going great until you came along. I feel its better you just undo what you did and let me get back to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To advance more than one line, call `next` in a loop:

```
for _ in range(times_to_advance):
    next(file_object)
```

---

As @MartijnPieters noted in the comments, this solution is not particularly efficient.  Its main advantage is simplicity.

If however your main concern is performance, you should use the code found in the [`consume()` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) of the `itertools` documentation:

```
from itertools import islice
next(islice(file_object, times_to_advance, times_to_advance), None)
```

Comment: Same remark for you: Looping yourself is rather inefficient; use `islice()` instead, if need be with start and stop equal to the number of lines to skip. Also see the [`consume()` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) in the itertools documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
def skip_n_items(n, iterator):
    for _ in range(n): next(iterator)
```

and then when you want to "skip 2 lines then get the third one"

```
skip_n_items(2, thefile)
amount = next(thefile)
```

(that's within e.g a `with open('the.file') as thefile:` block).

Comment: Looping yourself is rather inefficient; use `islice()` instead, if need be with start and stop equal to the number of lines to skip. Also see the [`consume()` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) in the `itertools` documentation.